# Chromium doesn't play mp4 / h.264 files in video tag

Tags: 14.04, 18.04, video, chromium, mp4

Firefox plays movie on the page: https://demotywatory.pl/4908893/Prawdziwy-pies-pasterski-dba-o-swoich-podopicznych

Chromium doesn't. it just shows the static backround image.

when i dig the page source and access the file directly: https://img1.demotywatoryfb.pl//uploads/201902/1549905806_IgmlZT.mp4

chromium plays it without any problem.

when i download the file, any video player plays the file without any problem

smplayer says:

```
Resolution: 460 x 258
Aspect ratio: 1.78295
Format: h264
Bitrate: 0 kbps
Frames per second: 30.000000
Selected codec: H.264
```

i have ubuntu mate 14.04 64bit, chromium 65.0.3325.181 (same observed on kubuntu 18.04 64bit, chromium 71.0.3578.98). i have installed `chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra` and `x264`

how to make chromium plays it?